# How to find rank of a matrices?

Tags: matrices

Here is the question given in my text book

> IF the rank of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 5\\2 & -4&a-4\\1&-2&a+1\end{bmatrix}$ is 1, then the value of a is:
>
> a) $-1$
> b) $ 2$
> c) $-6$
> d) $4$

however i don't know how to find the rank of a matrix and the explanation given in mt text book make no sense to me, can any one tell me how to find the rank of a matrix

Thanks  Akash

Comment: Use Gaussian elimination to get a triangular matrix.

Comment: This is probably easier to handle using the rank one condition directly.  Since all three rows are nonzero, they must be scalar multiples of each other.  Use this to find $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement the other answers, here's Gaussian elimination in action:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 5\\2 & -4&a-4\\1&-2&a+1\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 5\\0 & 0&a+6\\0&0&a+6\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 5\\0 & 0&a+6\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
In the first step I have added twice the first line to the second line, and then the first one to the third one. In the second step I have subtracted the second line from the third one.

Comment: yeah i have already solved the problem till here an i got stuck i don't know what to do next so thought i was doing wrong and asked the question--- can you tell what to do after that as what i understand about the Gaussian elimination now i will have to find the minor but i am getting 0 so what i am doing wrong

Comment: If you want to argue in terms of minors, extract the first two rows, and the first and third column to get $\det \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 5 \\ 0 & a+ 6 \end{bmatrix} = - (a+6)$, and you want this to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix is equal to the dimension of the linear space, spanned by its columns, in your case by the vectors $x=(-1,2,1), y=(2,-4,-2)$ and $z=(5,a-4,a+1)$. The only way the rank will be $1$ is if all vectors are colinear, meaning $y = \alpha x$ and $z=\beta x$ for some values $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Now, it is already obvious that $y=-2x$, so all you need is to set $a$ such that the equation

$$\beta x = z$$
will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix $A$ is said to be $r$ if :

1. There is atleast one **minor** of order $r$ which does not vanish *(the determinant of the minor is non-zero)*
2. Every minor of order $r+1$, if any, vanishes.

As per your question, any minor of order $2$ x $2$ and higher is going to vanish.

Or you may proceed with gaussian elimination, as already suggested.

Comment: can you elaborate it i didn't got anything---  The process of Gaussian elimination is the one given in my textbook and through that i am getting $0$